# Mysql Changing My Float Values

Tags: php, mysql, latitude-longitude

I have a database that stores lat and long coords, along with other fields.
The lat and long are set to float 10,8.

When running the following command ...

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO records(unique_id, city, st,zip,lat,lon) VALUES 
( '80936EN476', 'West Jordan', 'UT', '84088-5205', '40.59660', '-111.963' )
```

The insert is completed with no messages, but when the record is retrieved, the "lon" field has been set to -100.000000.

When I try to edit the value in phpMyAdmin, I get the following error.

> Warning: #1264 Out of range value for column 'lon' at row 1

Comment: To properly store lat and long in mysql set them as DECIMAL 9,6.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put more digits in front.

10,8 means 2 digits before decimal and 8 decimal digits.
try putting something like 12,8

Answer (score 1):

Do *not* use `(m,n)` on `FLOAT` or `DOUBLE`.  It leads to an extra rounding.  And, in your case, it leads to truncation in the upper digits.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the issue turned out to be the float values.
I changed it to 10,6 and that resolved the issue!